# Python Reshape Column Into Multiple Columns - Alternating Rows

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone suggest an efficient way of reshaping a column (in a python pandas dataframe) into multiple columns, with alternating column assignment. I could do this with a loop but wondering if there is a more elegant way. For an example, consider the following example:

**Added:** does anyone have a solution that will reshape every n values in a single column into n separate columns e.g. reshaping from a single column with n variables to n columns?

```
  Col
1 x1 
2 y1 
3 z1 
4 x2 
5 y2 
6 z2
7 x3 
8 y3 
9 z3 
..
```

to

```
  x  y  z 
1 x1 y1 z1 
2 x2 y2 z2 
3 x3 y3 z3  
...
```

Comment: Are your actual values similar to what you've given as sample data? i.e., you're trying to use the start and end of the string values as the indices and column names, respectively? Or are you only concerned with moving every three values into a row?

Comment: hey. Mainly concerned with moving every n values in a column into n rows !

Comment: Note the distinction in the two types of answers below. This is a detail that would be better to include in your problem description or in your sample data to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just reshape the underlying values, assuming that you have the correct number of values for the given shape and that you only care about ordering the values by shape without respect to the values themselves

```
s
    Col
1   x1
2   y1
3   z1
4   x2
5   y2
6   z2
7   x3
8   y3
9   z3

pd.DataFrame(s.to_numpy().reshape(3, 3))

    0   1   2
0   x1  y1  z1
1   x2  y2  z2
2   x3  y3  z3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df_final=(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df.Col.str[-1])['Col'].apply(list)
                   .values.tolist(),columns=['x','y','z']))
```

---

```
    x   y   z
0  x1  y1  z1
1  x2  y2  z2
2  x3  y3  z3
```

Comment: Might be worth noting: this assumes that the string values are actually the grouping keys, which is unclear from the original question

Answer (score 1):

You can use auxiliary variables to work as the row and column index, then apply `df.pivot`

```
df1['aux'] = df1.Col.str[:-1]
df1['aux_idx'] = df1.Col.str[-1:]
print(df1.pivot(index= 'aux_idx', columns='aux', values='Col'))
```

Output:

```
aux       x   y   z
aux_idx            
1        x1  y1  z1
2        x2  y2  z2
3        x3  y3  z3
```

For the same result by just counting the number of elements, use `df.index` module `n` as the key

```
df1['aux_idx'] = (df1.index-1)// 3
df1['aux'] = df1.Col.str[:-1]
print(df1.pivot(index= 'aux_idx', columns='aux', values='Col'))
```

Output:

```
aux       x   y   z
aux_idx            
0        x1  y1  z1
1        x2  y2  z2
2        x3  y3  z3
```

Comment: Might be worth noting: this assumes that the string values are actually the grouping keys, which is unclear from the original question

Comment: fair enough, like it is worth nothing that your solution works only if the data is ordered by 'buckets' of size 3, like you correctly state. Guess that the precision of the question is inevitably linked to the quality of the answers :)

Comment: Agreed, clarification needed from OP. I've edited my answer accordingly