# Python/Pandas: How to slice a column into multiple sections at particular rows

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

My laboratory instrument is providing a data set formatted in the following manner. For context, I have minimal experience with python.

| TTS | Cycle 1 |
| --- | --- |
| Wavelength (nm) | Absorbance |
| 100 | 12 |
| 200 | 23 |
| 300 | 17 |
| 400 | 14 |
| TTS | Cycle 2 |
| Wavelength (nm) | Absorbance |
| 100 | 73 |
| 200 | 25 |
| 300 | 179 |
| 400 | 15 |
| TTS | Cycle 3 |
| Wavelength (nm) | Absorbance |
| 100 | 60 |
| 200 | 45 |
| 300 | 12 |
| 400 | 100 |

I would like to separate each cycle into its own unique set of column as follows to facilitate followup analysis.

| Wavelength (Cycle 1) | Absorbance (Cycle 1) | Wavelength (Cycle 2) | Absorbance (Cycle 2) | Wavelength (Cycle 3) | Absorbance (Cycle 3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 12 | 100 | 73 | 100 | 60 |
| 200 | 23 | 200 | 25 | 200 | 45 |
| 300 | 17 | 300 | 179 | 300 | 12 |
| 400 | 14 | 400 | 15 | 400 | 100 |

There does not appear to be a delimiter for this form of separation within the pd.read_csv() functionality. I have not been able to find a way to perform this using df.iloc[], df.groupby(), nor the Series.str.split() functions.

A similar questions has been addressed previously here: [Python Reshape Column Into Multiple Columns - Alternating Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690658/python-reshape-column-into-multiple-columns-alternating-rows)

In this case, the number of rows in each cycle is not always consistent. Because of this, I don't believe reshaping will work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First create DataFrame with default `0,1` columns with `header=None` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    
print (df)
                  0           1
0               TTS     Cycle 1
1   Wavelength (nm)  Absorbance
2               100          12
3               200          23
4               300          17
5               400          14
6               TTS     Cycle 2
7   Wavelength (nm)  Absorbance
8               100          73
9               200          25
10              300         179
11              400          15
12              TTS     Cycle 3
13  Wavelength (nm)  Absorbance
14              100          60
15              200          45
16              300          12
17              400         100
```

Then create groups for identify cycles, here is compared first column by `TTS` and repeat second column value to `c` column and crete groups `g` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), so possible pivoting and create final columns names in list comprehension:

```
m = df[0].eq('TTS')
df1 = (df[~m & df[1].ne('Absorbance')]
       .assign(c=df[1].where(m).ffill().fillna(df.columns[1]),
               g=lambda x: x.groupby('c').cumcount()).pivot(index='g', columns='c')
       .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
       .rename(columns={0:'Wavelength', 1:'Absorbance'}))

df1.columns = [f'{a} ({b})' for a, b in df1.columns]
print (df1)
  Wavelength (Cycle 1) Absorbance (Cycle 1) Wavelength (Cycle 2)  \
g                                                                  
0                  100                   12                  100   
1                  200                   23                  200   
2                  300                   17                  300   
3                  400                   14                  400   

  Absorbance (Cycle 2) Wavelength (Cycle 3) Absorbance (Cycle 3)  
g                                                                 
0                   73                  100                   60  
1                   25                  200                   45  
2                  179                  300                   12  
3                   15                  400                  100
```

If wavelength is same per each cycle, is possible create one column:

```
m = df[0].eq('TTS')
df2 = (df[~m & df[1].ne('Absorbance')]
       .assign(c=df[1].where(m).ffill().fillna(df.columns[1]),
               g=lambda x: x.groupby('c').cumcount()).pivot(index=0, columns='c', values=1)
       .rename_axis(index='Wavelength', columns=None)
       .rename(columns= lambda x: f'Absorbance ({x})')
       .reset_index()
       )

print (df2)
  Wavelength Absorbance (Cycle 1) Absorbance (Cycle 2) Absorbance (Cycle 3)
0        100                   12                   73                   60
1        200                   23                   25                   45
2        300                   17                  179                   12
3        400                   14                   15                  100
```